# GCSE similar/congruent triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

looking for some advice with my GCSE revision in tackling the following please:

Q10 b and Q11:

[image]

For Question 10, I so far have that EF = 28.8cm and BC = 48cm, using properties for similar triangles. But how do we use that information to find areas? I can't seem to find anything in my notes which would help me find the area.

And for question 11 I am struggling to see where I should start, a hint or two to help me get the ball rolling would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: First one is simply similarity of triangles. Consider ratio of sides

Comment: @KingTut Thanks, I was referring to Q10 part b? Struggling with the area

Comment: @KD Sides are in ratio, area in ratio square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{A_{ABD}}{A_{EFB}}=(\frac{AB}{EB})^2$$
This flows from the similarity: $AB=kEB$, $h_1=kh_2$ (where $h_1$ and $h_2$ are corresponding heights) so $A_{ABD}=\frac{1}{2}k^2EB\cdot h_2=k^2A_{EFB}$

[image]

Solution for #11:
[image]

Comment: Any possible tips for Q11?

Comment: @K.D7: for #11, observer that $\triangle{PUT}$ is similar to $\triangle{QTR}$

Comment: Hi sorry I have just had another look at this but you have shown me the ratios from ABD to EFB. How does that help in finding area of triangle ABC?

Comment: @K.D7: $A_{AFE}=A_{ABD}-A_{EFB}$ then use the similarity of $AFE$ and $ABC$.

Comment: forgive my ignorance if I am wrong but does your equation not give the area of trapezium AEFD? What would I do then?

Comment: @K.D7: you are right, see my updated answer

Comment: Incredible. Thank you so much. If you find the time may I please have a similar style solution for Q11? These are the last two questions I could not answer in my textbook.

Comment: @K.D7: You are welcome. I posted the solution for #11, if you like it, accept my answer.

Comment: I have accepted it. Sorry I only just got round to doing it! Just sat all my mocks and went very well! Thanks so much

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again but may I ask what the m stands for in your solution?

Comment: @K.D7: No problem. $m$ stands for measure of angle. It's not really necessary at the last step, the triangles will be congruent because all sides are congruent.